# how to pass realtime form arguments to a python script called by a django app

Tags: python, django

my django app calls a python cgi script:

```
def query(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
    output = subprocess.check_output(['python', 'query.cgi']).decode('utf-8')
    return HttpResponse(output, content_type="text/html")
```

The query.cgi will be called by a form. How do I pass form args like "name=one&type=two" to the cgi. When I do subprocess.check_output(['python', 'query.cgi', 'name=one', 'type=two']). It works, but how do I pass the realtime online form input to cgi? Thanks a lot!

Comment: if it's python do you really need a subprocess?

Answer (score 0):

They're passed in the `GET` dictionary from `request`:

```
foo = request.GET['foo']
subprocess.check_output(['python', 'query.cgi', 'foo=' + foo])
```

You can also use

```
request.GET.get('foo', 'def')
```

to have a default value if the key is missing.

Comment: @user2607925 remember to vote on, and accept, useful answers.